# Gsub-ing multiple substrings to an empty string

Tags: ruby, gsub

I often remove substrings from strings by doing this:

```
"don't use bad words like".gsub("bad", "").gsub("words", "").gsub("like", "")
```

What's a more concise/better way of excising long lists of substrings from a string in Ruby?

Comment: Are you sure you want two consecutive spaces left after each matching site in the middle?

Comment: Nope it's just an example, but thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Nobody likes to use `.delete`?!?

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove substrings rather than words? See the example in my solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with nronas' answer, however people tend to forget about [Regexp.union](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```
str = "don't use bad words like"
str.gsub(Regexp.union('bad', 'words', 'like'), '')
# or
str.gsub(Regexp.union(['bad', 'words', 'like']), '')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always use regex when you gsubing :P. like:

```
str = "don't use bad words like"
str.gsub(/bad|words|like/, '')
```

I hope that helps

Comment: You must change the code every time the list of bad words changes.  That should be a variable.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit2:** Upon reflection, I think what I have below (or any solution that first breaks the string into an array of words) is really what you want. Suppose:

```
str = "Becky darned her socks before playing badmitten."
bad_words = ["bad", "darn", "socks"]
```

Which of the following would you want?

```
str.gsub(Regexp.union(*bad_words), '')
  #=> "Becky ed her  before playing mitten."
```

or

```
(str.split - bad_words).join(' ')
  #=> "Becky darned her before playing badmitten."
```

Alternatively,

```
bad_words.reduce(str.split) { |arr,bw| arr.delete(bw); arr }.join(' ')
  #=> "Becky darned her before playing badmitten."
```

**:2tidE**

**Edit1:** I've come to my senses and purged my solution.  It was much too elaborate (and inefficient) for such a simple problem. I've just left an observation. **:1tidE**

If you want to end up with just a single space between words, you need to take a different tack:

```
(str.split - bad_words).join(' ')
  #=> "don't use
```

Comment: You can go one step further and do `h = Hash.new{|h, k| k}.merge(bad_words.product(['']).to_h)`.

Comment: Yes, good idea, @sawa. I wanted to just use `str.gsub(/\w+/,h)`, but had a problem.  What was I doing wrong?

Comment: @sawa, I get `str.gsub(/\w+/,h) => "'    "` with `str
=> "don't use bad words like"` and `h => {"bad"=>"", "words"=>"", "like"=>""}`.  Probably something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: I thought you tried with what I suggested as `h`. With your `h`, the missing keys will return `nil`, and that will become empty strings.

Comment: @sawa, thanks for the explanation. I modified by answer some using `Hash.new` with a block, inspired by your comment.

Comment: I already wrote it in my answer because you hadn't used it in yours.

Comment: It is not good idea to do assignment `h[k] = ` in default value block in this case. Every time a new word is met, that entry is added to the hash. It can grow huge. And there is no reason for doing that.

Comment: You're right. Oh, well. It's getting late here, later there.

Answer (score 1):

I already suggested this to Cary, but it's here:

```
bad_words = %w[bad words like]
h = Hash.new{|h, k| k}.merge(bad_words.product(['']).to_h)
"don't use bad words like".gsub(/\w+/, h)
```